# Robot: Set and use a local list in Test Cases

Tags: robotframework

I need to set a list inside a test case and use this list in [SETUP] to pass this list to a python script, how can I achieve this?

```
TEST-List
    @{lst}    Create List    a    b
    @{tmp}    Set Test Variable    @{lst}
    [Setup]   Receive List ${tmp}  ${another_var}
```

When I try the code above, I got this error:
`Variable '{${tmp}' not found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`[Setup]`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown) setting is used for performing actions before a test case. Its purpose is to set up a state for your test. That implies that it happens (executes) before test steps, regardless of where you type it.

In your case, `[Setup]   Receive List   ${tmp}    ${another_var}` is executed first, and `${tmp}` variable has not been declared yet.

The solution might be to move the declaration of `${tmp}` to a suite level.

Comment: I forgot to say, that i'm new to robot ... but if this call, change in all test cases, you need to have multiple list in Variables area,  there is no way to define a list like [Setup]   Receive List    [a,b,c] and pass this way to the python side

Comment: I don't know exactly  what you're trying to achieve. There's usually a way, but sometimes it's in how you structure your tests.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the code in `[Setup]` is run before any other code in the test. Therefore, `@{lst}` and `@{tmp}` are undefined at the time that it runs.

The simplest solution is to create a local keyword that performs everything you need in the setup, and then call that keyword from `[Setup]`.

Example

```
*** Keywords ***
Initialize test
    @{lst}    Create List    a    b
    @{tmp}    Set Test Variable    @{lst}
    Receive List  ${tmp}  ${another_var}

*** Test Cases ***
TEST-List
    [Setup]  Initialize test
    # ... rest of your test goes here ...
```